# Wordpress Ajax reload with updated query vars

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a front end filter that alters query vars in the url.

http://example.com/events/?zone=strength&days=28th&locations=136

zone and days are taxonomies, locations is a meta query from a custom field.

I have 3 select inputs with listings of each query var, when you select one of them the page reloads with the new query in the url, and it works as intended.

It's all working fine, but I think having ajax reload the loop instead of a full pageload would make it even better.

My jQuery (probably written poorly):

```js
// function to split up URL queries
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split('&');
  for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split('=');
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }

  return false;
} 

// on ready, set the select values to the url queries
var zone = getQueryVariable('zone');
var days = getQueryVariable('days');
var locations = getQueryVariable('locations');

if(zone) {
  $(".event-filter .zone").val(zone); 
}
if(days) {
  $(".event-filter .day").val(days); 
}
if(locations) {
  $(".event-filter .location").val(locations);
}

// on select change, detect what changed and update url
jQuery('.event-filter select').on('change', function() {

  var params = {};

  if($(".event-filter .zone option:selected").val() != 'zone'){
    var zone = $(".event-filter .zone option:selected").val();
    params['zone'] = zone;
  }
  if($(".event-filter .day option:selected").val() != 'day'){
    var days = $(".event-filter .day option:selected").val() 
    params['days'] = days;
  }
  if($(".event-filter .location option:selected").val() != 'location'){
    var locations = $(".event-filter .location option:selected").val()
    params['locations'] = locations;
  }
  // create new url
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  if ($.isEmptyObject(params)) {
    var new_url = path; 
  } else {
    var new_url = path + '?' + jQuery.param(params);     
  }

  // reload page
  window.location.href = new_url;      

});
```

It's that new_url variable I want to reload as the url with ajax, and make the loop run again with the new query vars.

My Loop:

```html
// Check if query vars are being used in the URL. 
$days = get_query_var('days',FALSE);
$zone = get_query_var('zone',FALSE); 

// Created tax_query array, supporting multiple arrays where all conditions must be met 
$tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

// Set days variable with terms from the query var in url
if( ($days) ) {
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'day',
    'field'     => 'slug',
    'terms'     => $days,
  );
}

// Set zone variable with terms from the query var in url
if( ($zone)) {
  $tax_query[] = array(
    taxonomy'  => 'zone',
    'field'     => 'slug',
    'terms'     => $zone,
  );
}

// Check if locations query var is used
if(isset($_GET['locations']) && !empty($_GET['locations'])){
  $locations[] = array(
    'key' => 'event_location',
    'value' => $_GET['locations'],
    'compare' => 'IN'
  );
}

// Load both taxonomy query and meta query arrays into their respective args!
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'event', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => $tax_query,
  'meta_query' => $locations
);

$events = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

My thinking is that I should create a function with the above loop, that is called whenever a select field is changed with jQuery/ajax, instead of reloading the page. Is this correct?

How do I make it load only the section with the loop in it, and not the entire page, from the changed new_url jquery variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you want to adapt your current approach to replace the redirect (reload) with an AJAX solution.

> How do I make it load only the section with the loop in it, and not the entire page, from the changed new_url jquery variable?

Let's think about the processing:

1. You'll grab the parameters as you are now, except they will become part of the data packet going back to the server via [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).
2. You'll remove the code that appends the query vars to the URL and does the reload.  That's not needed any longer.
3. Then using `$.post` you'll send the parameters to the server.  Then server checks the security nonce.  If it's okay, you run the PHP code to fetch the query and build the events HTML.
4. Then the server echoes out the new HTML and does a `die()` or `wp_die()`.
5. The script `$.post` receives the response, which is the new HTML string.  Then you'll remove the old HTML and replace it with the new.

Still with me?  Let's walk through what you need to do to convert your code to the new approach. I wrote up an answer explaining that to another PO, which [you can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006710/wordpress-how-do-i-ajax-additional-posts/41007047#41007047).

### Setting the URL target for the Script

AJAX needs a URL to talk back to the server.  In WordPress, we use the `admin-ajax.php` file.  You will want to localize the parameter to pass it from the server to the script when you enqueue.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', 'path-to/filename.js', array('jquery'), $version );
wp_localize_script( 'your-script-handle', 'eventParams', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
));
```

Notice that the localize command is targeted the handle you give your script when you enqueue it.  What it does is:

- Passes the array to the script
- It's stored as an object then in the script using the variable `eventParams`

In the script, you would receive use the admin ajax URL like this:

```
$.post( eventParams.ajaxurl, dataPacket, function(htmlResponse) {

});
```

### Security

Next, you need to add a nonce for security.  I'd recommend adding a [hidden input field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field).

### Building the Data Packet

The [jQuery `$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) construct passes the data packet to the server.  You can see above that I set it as a variable called `dataPacket`. You need to build that object before running `$.post()`.

I've adapted your code as a starting point for you:

```
(function($, window, document){
    "use strict";

    var init = function() {
        $('.event-filter select').on('change', eventSelectHandler);
    }

    var eventSelectHandler = function() {

        var dataPacket = {
            action: 'event_filter',
            security: getSecurity(),
            zone: getZone(),
            days: getDay(),
            locations: getLocation()
        };

        $.post( eventParams.ajaxurl, dataPacket, function(htmlResponse) {
            // add your processing code
        });

    }

    function getSecurity() {
        // you'll grab that from the nonce field and then
        // return it.
    }

    function getZone() {
        return getSelected( '.zone', 'zone' );
    }

    function getDay() {
        return getSelected( '.day', 'day' );
    }

    function getLocation() {
        return getSelected( '.location', 'location' );
    }

    function getSelected( classAttribute, compareValue ) {
        var $element = $( ".event-filter " + classAttribute + " option:selected");
        if ( $element.length < 1 ) {
            return '';
        }

        var optionSelected = $element.val();

        if ( optionSelected != compareValue ) {
            return optionSelected;
        }

        return '';
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        init();
    });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Look at the function `eventSelectHandler()`.  Notice that you are first building the data packet.  Then once you have it built, it's passed into the `$.post`.

### PHP Side

Now on the PHP side, you will need to register a callback function to the WordPress AJAX events.  These are determined by the action name you gave in the data packet.

You'll use [`wp_ajax_{your action name}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for logged in users and [`wp_ajax_nopriv_{your action name}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) for guests.

It would look like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_event_filter', 'process_event_filter_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_event_filter', 'process_event_filter_ajax_request' );
function process_event_filter_ajax_request() {
    // Check the security nonce first
    // If it fails, it returns immediately.

    // The parameters are in $_POST['zone']
    $zone     = strip_tags( $_POST['zone'] );
    $days     = strip_tags( $_POST['days'] );
    $location = strip_tags( $_POST['location'] );

    // do your work here

    // build the HTML

    wp_die();
}
```

Your code with the `WP_Query` handling would be part of the above AJAX processing.  You'll need to adapt your code into the above callback.

That should be enough to get you started on the right track.

Comment: Tonya, thank you so much this is fantastic and has definitely put me on the right track. Amazing and detailed reply, appreciate it!